# PhoneGap based App does not work after After App update in iOS5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, cordova

I have a PhoneGap based iOS app which uses SQLite DB for offline storage. The app is not working after an app update in iOS 5.1. The same app is working fine in versions below 5.1.

I explored few things and my analysis is

1. When we install a app iOS creates a separate sandbox for that and all the data related to that app goes in to that.
2. in iOS5.1 when we update an app new sandbox is created and the contents from old sandbox is moved here.
3. For WebSQL i.e SQLite for PhoneGap in iOS 5.1 the DB is stored under caches folder(volatile storage). But in previous version of iOS the SQLite DB was stored under Documents folder in Sandbox which is persistent storage.
4. The real problem is there is a file called ".preferences" in caches/preferences that has the path of websql DB. when i do an app update the sandbox path changes but in this file the previous sandbox is path is still available due to this the app is not working as the previous path is already deleted from device.

Is this an Apple issue or can it be resolved by a developer?

Comment: Are you suggesting that SQLite doesn't work at all in iOS 5.1 or it just breaks on phones that migrate OS with the app previously installed?  Does SQLite work for a fresh build/new install on iOS 5.1?

Comment: in iOS 5.1, After app update app is not able to connect to SQLite. I found a piece of information from PhoneGap on this problem. They clearly state this as an Apple issue and already abug has been raised regd this. http://phonegap.com/2012/04/18/ios-5-1-and-the-embedded-uiwebview-with-cordova/

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by

The path referred by iOS to find WEB DB(SQLite) and Local storage is stored in NSUserDefaults.
So when i launch the app every time i check the path information and make sure it matches new sandbox path if not i set the value for that Key and now the app works fine.

NSUserDefault Key referred to SQLite path is WebDatabaseDirectory.

If Apple releases a fix for this issue in their next release, this code is not required.

Comment: I don't use PhoneGap but I have to say that is a great workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cordova-1.6.0 or above this.

When  I changed to  cordova-1.6.0 , my problem is fixed.